# How to get large collection of products?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have a store with over 100K products. I am using this code to get all my products.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($model  as $product) {
     $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
     echo $p->getName();
     echo $p->getDescription();
     echo $p->shortDescription();
}
```

But it shows nothing. This code works where i have only less number of products in my store.
So how to get all my 100K products?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'descryption','short_descryption'))
    ->setPageSize(1000);
$numberOfPages = $model->getLastPageNumber();

for ($i=1; $i<=$numberOfPages; $i++) {
    $products = $model->setCurPage($i)->load();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo $product->getName() . '<br />'; 
        echo $product->getDescription() . '<br />'; 
        echo $product->shortDescription() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code does not work when i set page size to 100K. Any other good idea??

Comment: Set page size to 1k or 10k and it will be work.

Comment: just remove this line `->setPageSize(1000);` simple :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can handle loading large collection, take a look at [Magento: Working with large collection](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-working-with-large-collection/). Take a look at `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk()`, base on what your trying to accomplish I would mysql/query.

```
public function resourceIteratorMethod()
{
    $productCollections = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk(
    $productCollections->getSelect(),
    array(array($this,'productCallback'))
    );
}
public function productCallback($args)
{
    $cust = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $cust->setData($args['row']);

    echo $cust->getName()."\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am new in magento. So i am sorry if it is a stupid question. 
i placed the body of resourceIteratorMethod into some phtml file and also placed productCallback function into the block class of that phtml. But productCallBack function is not called. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If by "shows nothing" you mean to say that the Web browser simply returns a blank page, you should know that PHP needs to hold all of `$model` in memory. You then proceed to loop through it 100k times and call `load` on every single one of them, which fires off more requests to the database. That requires a massive amount of memory. Increase your memory. Also, be aware that code like this will cripple your store the moment you get just a few people browsing concurrently, unless you plan to install 1TB memory.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But is there any way to optimize the code?

Comment: If you want to display 100k products on a single page, no, there is no optimization that will help you. It's bad and will never even reasonably scale for a *single user*. If your intention is to display a product listing, use pagination.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to load all products with all information in one run without using up all memory you could do something like

```
$productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->getAllIdsCache();
// Returns a array with 100k ids

foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
    // Load one product
    $product = Mage::getModel()->load($productId);
    /** @var $product \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getDescription();
    echo $product->getShortDescription();

    $product->clearIntance();
}
```

If you know which attributes to get you could also just add those to your filter and iterate that.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    /** @var $product \Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getDescription();
    echo $product->getShortDescription();
}
```

The first one would take less memory than the second one because it wont hold old information in memory.